# Apache beam pipeline Java : Records not writing to the destination file in sequential order

Tags: azure-blob-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am Using Apache beam pipeline to transfer the csv file from one container to another container in Azure storage and can able to transfer the file successfully, but records inside the destination file not in sequential order. Below is the code I am using to transfer the file.

```
String format = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS3")).toString();

String connectionString = "<<AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING>>"; 
        
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
options.as(BlobstoreOptions.class).setAzureConnectionString(connectionString);
        
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(TextIO.read().from("azfs://storageaccountname/containername/CSVSample.csv"))
.apply("",FileIO.<String>write().to("azfs://storageaccountname/containername/"+format+"/").withNumShards(1).withSuffix(".csv")
        .via(TextIO.sink()));
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Beam PCollections are not ordered.  If you need order, you can [group by a key](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) (in which to impose an order) and order the value set, emitting it as a single string element containing newlines.